# Windows command line to get physical drive size in GB

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, vbscript

I want to display all the attached diskdrive model, name, index and size in command line
I am using the below simple code

```
    wmic diskdrive GET index,caption,name,size /format:table
```

Output

```
Caption                   Index  Name                Size
SAMSUNG SSD PM830 2.5" 7  0      \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0  256052966400
Seagate backup plus       1      \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE1  536870912000
```

I want the same output as the above except that i would like the size to be displayed in GB

I think there is some way to do that using for loops and temp vb files.

I am specifically looking for windows cmd code. Can anybody help?

I am able to do the size conversion and display it on cmd

```
    for /f "tokens=1,2" %a in ('WMIC DISKDRIVE GET Name^,Size ^|FINDSTR /I /V "Name"') do @echo wsh.echo "%a" ^& " size=" ^& FormatNumber^(cdbl^(%b^)/1024/1024/1024, 2^)^& " GiB" > %temp%\tmp.vbs & @if not "%b"=="" @echo( & @cscript //nologo %temp%\tmp.vbs & del %temp%\tmp.vbs
```

Output

```
\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0 Size=238.47 (GB)
```

But i am still not able to display the model name correctly.. I am just not able to get my for loop to run as intended (in my case the model name has spaces in between  The below code works to just get the models printed.

```
    for /f "tokens=1-5 skip=1" %a in ('wmic diskdrive GET model') do @echo. %a %b %c %d %e
```

Output

```
SAMSUNG SSD PM830 2.5" 7
```

Can someone help me in combining both the codes such that it displays like

```
SAMSUNG SSD PM830 2.5" 7  \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0  Size=238.47 (GB)
```

Comment: [windows batch to convert bytes to GB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14880236/windows-batch-to-convert-bytes-to-gb) and [How to split a string in a Windows batch file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707058/how-to-split-a-string-in-a-windows-batch-file).

Comment: Sure, it can be done.  You can send WMIC's output to a file (using something like /OUTPUT: or by redirection) and have VBScript read the file.  Or, you could just have VBScript interact with WMI (instead of using WMIC), which might be easier.  Once you get the numbers into VBScript, division ought to be simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculations in cmd with set /A are limited to signed 32bit numbers, so you need vbscript or PowerShell to do the math. 
Instead of using batch, wmic and vbscript I have here a hybrid batch/vbscript file which eliminates the need to create temporary files. A drawback is an echoed `rem &` which is required to have both script versions accept the file.

Save this as a .cmd/.bat file

```
rem^ &@cls&cscript //nologo //e:vbscript "%~f0"&Pause&exit /b
On Error Resume Next
sComputer = "."
Set oWMI = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & sComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set cItems = oWMI.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_DiskDrive",,48)
sOut = ""
For Each oItem in cItems
  sOut = sOut & JL(26,oItem.Model) & JL(20,oItem.Name) & "Size=" & _
  JR(8,FormatNumber(cdbl(oItem.Size)/1024/1024/1024, 2)) & " (GiB)" &vbCRLF
Next
Set cItems = Nothing

wscript.echo sOut

Function JL(Places, Value) ' Justify Left within Places
  If len (Value) < Places then
    JL=Left(Value & Space(Places), Places)
  Else
    JL=Value
   End If
end Function 
Function JR(Places, Value) ' Justify Right within Places
  If Len (Value) < Places then
    JR = Right(Space(Places) & Value, Places)
  Else
    JR=Value
   End If
end Function
```

Output on my system (german locale)

```
Hitachi HDS722020ALA330   \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE2  Size=1.863,01 (GiB)
VB0250EAVER               \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0  Size=  232,88 (GiB)
ST2000DL003-9VT166        \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE1  Size=1.863,01 (GiB)

Drücken Sie eine beliebige Taste . . .
```